# Weblogic JMS client throws DispatcherException when trying to commit after long processing

Tags: java, jms, weblogic, weblogic11g

I am working on a JMS client for WebLogic 11g (WebLogic Server 10.3.6.0). The client is based on `wlthint3client.jar` library. The client uses asynchronous API (listeners) to read messages from JMS queue. Client is multi-threaded and uses multiple parallel JMS consumers.

Weblogic JMS server is configured to have a JMS transaction timeout of 10 minutes, yet I have problems with commiting transactions that are over 6 minutes long. This happens only when there are many long transactions going at the same time.

Is such case commit fails with following exception:

```
weblogic.jms.common.JMSException: weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherException: java.rmi.RemoteException: Could not establish a connection with -6273788781435586093S:host:[7001,7001,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]:domain:server, java.io.IOException: Bootstrap request to JVMID -6273788781435586093S:host:[7001,7001,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]:domain:server got an error or timed out; nested exception is:
    java.io.IOException: Bootstrap request to JVMID -6273788781435586093S:host:[7001,7001,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]:domain:server got an error or timed out; nested exception is:
    java.rmi.ConnectException: Could not establish a connection with -6273788781435586093S:host:[7001,7001,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]:domain:server, java.io.IOException: Bootstrap request to JVMID -6273788781435586093S:host:[7001,7001,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]:domain:server got an error or timed out; nested exception is:
    java.io.IOException: Bootstrap request to JVMID -6273788781435586093S:host:[7001,7001,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]:domain:server got an error or timed out
    at weblogic.jms.dispatcher.DispatcherAdapter.convertToJMSExceptionAndThrow(DispatcherAdapter.java:116)
    at weblogic.jms.dispatcher.DispatcherAdapter.dispatchSyncNoTran(DispatcherAdapter.java:61)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.commit(JMSSession.java:1224)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.commit(JMSSession.java:1198)
    at weblogic.jms.client.WLSessionImpl.commit(WLSessionImpl.java:108)
```

Some other observations:

- It seems my client only can handle 5 messages at a time. I have more consumers, let say 10, I have more available messages in the queue, but still only 5 are processed in parallel.
- If I configure the client to use < 5 consumers then the problem does not occur.
- If there are < 5 parallel long transactions - the problem does not occur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution of the problem is to set a property on JVM running the client application `-Dweblogic.ThreadPoolSize=N+1`, where N is number of asynchronous listeners used by the client.

If you set it equal to N, and N messages are received and stuck for more than 4 minutes, then your commit will fail with aforementioned exception.

Why? I guess when you have all the listener threads busy processing incoming messages, there is nobody there to talk to the server and keep the connection alive. This is confirmed by [Oracle documentation on T3 connection heartbeats](http://%20https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13721/rmi_t3.htm#WLRMI143):

> Any two Java programs with a valid T3 connection — such as two server instances, or a server instance and a Java client — use periodic point-to-point "heartbeats " to announce and determine continued availability [...]

and

> The frequency with which a server instance issues heartbeats is determined by the heartbeat interval, which by default is 60 seconds.
>
> The number of missed heartbeats from a peer that a server instance waits before deciding the peer is unavailable is determined by the heartbeat period, which by default, is 4. Hence, each server instance waits up to 240 seconds, or 4 minutes, with no messages—either heartbeats or other communication—from a peer before deciding that the peer is unreachable.

and in another place:

> WebLogic client thread pools are configured differently than WebLogic server thread-pools, and are not self tuning. WebLogic clients have a specific thread pool that is used for handling incoming requests from the server, such as JMS MessageListener invocations. This pool can be configured via the command-line property:
>
> -Dweblogic.ThreadPoolSize=n

[enter link description here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/PERFM/jmstuning.htm#PERFM462)